# Using 18650 batteries to power TV during power outage

Tags: batteries

I have a ton of 18650 batteries. As a fun project, mostly to learn. I would like to build a battery pack with these batteries, and power my TV when there is an outage. Can I just match the AC 120 V ~ 50/60 Hz 3.2 A with a battery configuration?

Comment: There is no direct match. You need a converter circuit called an inverter.

Comment: batteries produce DC. You write your TV needs AC. I think that answers your question.

Comment: It is impossible without additional equipment. If you ready to equip yourself with an inverter - yes. You would have to build a battery pack of let's say 7 batteries in series, each of batteries shall consist around 5 - 20 parallel batteries (do not forget BMS system!). Now, connect the output of the battery pack to the input of inverter (to change DC produced by your batteries to AC needed for your TV and to match the voltage).

Comment: You may be surprised how easily this could work.  Many switching power supplies will accept DC input, and operate from a surprisingly low voltage.  Stack a bunch of cells to total about 60VDC.  Apply the 60VDC to the power lead of the TV.  If is doesn't work, flip the polarity and try it again.  You might also try higher voltages (up to maybe 100VDC.)

Comment: With an inverter you absolutely can but alot of things can go wrong.

Answer (score 1):

@JRE's  advice is potentially true but also potentially fatal for the TV.
It may "just work". It's quite possible, as he says.
It MAY just smoke.
Probably not -  are you feeling lucky?

Also, 60V or more is potentially fatal for you.
**60VDC CAN KILL** - it is not worth playing with like this unless you are "suitably expert". You're not. Really.

Safer is to build a 12V or 24V pack and obtain a commercial DC (12 OR 24v) to AC mains converter. Even building a converter yourself is FAR safer than a HV DC battery.    Switching DC at more than about 30 VDC is far more hazardous than is usually appreciated. At 48 VDC the actual voltage starts to get dangerous and above that - fatalities are easy.

Answer (score 0):

It's entirely possible.

Given a TV is not a high drain device, the number of cells will also be acceptable.

What you would need is:

- a charger for 12V li-ion
- an inverted 12VCC to 120VAC
- a number of li-ion cells (depending on the required uptime).

Now about the actual math: Let's say you use 18650 cells of 3000mAh (which are available in plenty quantities at a cheap price ): 3 cells in series will give you the desired 12V and provide 3Ah of capacity. But a single cell 3-set will not suffice for capacity or drained current. So, depending on the up-time you want you just put enough 3-Series in parallel. **If you use 10 such sets, 30 cells in total, you will get 30Ah capacity.**

If you TV drains **30W**, you will have a few hours of uptime from a 30Ah pack.

In ideal case (no conversion loss) you would get around **10h of uptime**. In the no-ideal case you will have to consider the quality of your inverted (how much of the power is converted in usable AC and how much is lost in the process).

Comment: In English, "pair" means two - you should say "three-cell groups".

Comment: True, it's a little harder to explain without using the terms nSnP used by the experienced ones.